Video game where the hero gets transported to another world with his sister to aid a king in a war
I remember playing a game, similar to Vestaria Saga, both in gameplay and style. The story is typical isekai, where main hero gets transported to another world with his sister to aid a king in a war.
I remember some other characters; a girl with purple hair who is tired of fighting for that king, and another girl with brown hair and green eyes, using a spear if I remember correctly, who takes care of the main hero, teaching him the language of this world. There was also another red-haired girl who did not know the value of life and the main hero teaches her that.
Lastly, there was a king that can force the main hero to do whatever he asked him to. His daughter isn't as heartless as her father and befriends the main hero's sister.
That's all I can remember. I found that game on SteamUnlocked, yet I couldn't find it there anymore. I'll be grateful for every answer.

Vestaria Saga is a clone of Fire Emblem. The obvious match would be Isekai Emblem (isekai theme, purple hair, two siblings sent to fight an evil king, etc), but there's no way you got that on SteamUnlocked since it's a fanhack; https://feuniverse.us/t/isekai-emblem-the-tales-two-complete-v1-3-1/12640

No, that's not it. Do you know anything else that resembles Vestaria Saga?

I found it. It's "Aselia the Eternal -The Spirit of Eternity Sword":

You are Takamine Yuuto, an orphan who lives only to care for his sister and ensure they make it through their ordinary everyday lives (with a little help from their friends). One day he is suddenly interrupted by a call from beyond this Earth - he has been summoned through a mystical portal to the distant land of Phantasmagoria!
With his sister Kaori held hostage, Yuuto must fight as an Etranger - a warrior of power - and take up the sword to fight alongside the beautiful female Spirits who protect the land from the evil that threatens to consume it. With these new comrades, a tale of desperate heroism, newfound purpose and tender romance unfolds...


I know, just a few more hours before 2 days pass

I had forgotten about that timer..
